# How to make TopMost toggle switch

Tags: c#, toggleswitch, bunifu

Hello there I'm trying to make TopMost toggle switch here's the code:
private void bunifuiOSSwitch1_OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
private void bunifuiOSSwitch1_OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Main main = new Main();
            if(bunifuiOSSwitch1.Value == true)
            {
                main.TopMost = true;
            }
            else
            {
                main.TopMost = false;
            }
        }
```

At first it worked when toggled to true and worked when toggled to false but when I tried to retoggle it on it didn't worked after that I tried to change the code again but that didn't worked too...
Now it doesn't even TopMost.

Comment: You're creating a new, different `Main` with each toggle...so you'll never be able to change the state of the existing `Main`. Move the declaration and creation up a level (outside the event handler).  You'll have to do some extra checks to make sure that `Main` is in the right state to be displayed.

Comment: You mean Main main = new Main():? If yes should I use using Windows Forms or using Main? I'm new to c#

Comment: Main is a form... isn't it?!  I don't understand your last comment/ question.

Comment: Yes Main is the form that I want to make TopMost

Comment: But is this code inside of Main?  Are you trying to make the CURRENT form (which is Main) toggle its topmost property?...or are you trying to show a second form and toggle that?

Comment: I made a new form named Settings.cs so from there I can toggle TopMost.

Comment: So in your Form "Settings", you want to toggle TopMost of the ALREADY EXISTING "Main" form?  And presumably, Settings is being displayed directly from Main?

Comment: Yes you're right but in Main right now there is no TopMost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is pass a reference to Main into your Settings form.  One way to do this is when you call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`:

```
// ... in Form Main ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.Show(this); // pass in this instance of Main as the "owner" of settings
}
```

Then, over in Settings, you can cast the `.Owner` property back to the `Main` type and take action on it:

```
// ... in Settings Form ...
private void bunifuiOSSwitch1_OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner!=null && this.Owner is Main)
    {
        Main main = (Main)this.Owner;
        main.TopMost = (bunifuiOSSwitch1.Value == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it